# HTML <OL> shows 1 for every dynamic generated option

Tags: html, html-lists

I am using the following php code to render different options with `<ol>` tag. Everything is fine except `<ol>` shows 1 for each option.

```
 <ol>
     <li>
         <h3><?php echo $question ?></h3>
         <div>
             <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $id ?>]"
                    id = "php   " value="<?php echo $answer1 ?>" />
             <label for = "php"> <?php echo $answer1 ?></label>                     
         </div>
         <div>
             <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $id ?>]"
                    id = "php" value="<?php echo $answer2 ?>" />
             <label for = "php"><?php echo $answer2 ?><label>
         </div>
         <div>
             <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $id ?>]"
                    id = "php" value="<?php echo $answer3 ?>" />
             <label for = "php"><?php echo $answer3 ?></label>
         </div>
         <div>
             <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $id ?>]"
                    id = "php" value="<?php echo $answer4 ?>" />
             <label for = "php"><?php echo $answer4 ?></label>
         </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I have no idea why you'd want to make an OL with only 1 LI containing 4 DIV's with the options

Comment: And before you forget, the `label for` must refer to the *unique* ID of the input you're refering to

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a separate `<li>` tag for each numbered list item.

So your markup should look something like that:

```
<h3><?php echo $question ?></h3>

<ol>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $id ?>]" id="php<?=$answerId1?>" value="<?php echo $answer1 ?>" />
        <label for="php<?=$answerId1?>">
            <?php echo $answer1 ?>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $id ?>]" id="php<?=$answerId2?>" value="<?php echo $answer2 ?>" />
        <label for="php<?=$answerId2?>">
            <?php echo $answer2 ?>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $id ?>]" id="php<?=$answerId3?>" value="<?php echo $answer3 ?>" />
        <label for="php<?=$answerId3?>">
            <?php echo $answer3 ?>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $id ?>]" id="php<?=$answerId4?>" value="<?php echo $answer4 ?>" />
        <label for="php<?=$answerId4?>">
            <?php echo $answer4 ?>
        </label>
    </li>
</ol>
```

**P.S** I also noticed you use the same `id` attribute on all of your radio inputs. It's not valid HTML, since element IDs [should be unique](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really).

**P.S2** Also your approach to print out every question in a list manually doesn't look very practical. I would try something like this:

```
<ol>
   <?php foreach($answers as $answer): ?>
   <li>
      <label>
          <input type="radio" 
                 name="question[<?=$id ?>]" 
                 value="<?=$answer?>" />
          <?=$answer?>
      </label>
   </li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: You might want to edit your code to add those unique ID's (and remove those trailing spaces at the first one). I guess his ID isn't unique as it's also used in the name.

Comment: The ID in the `name` must remain the same. Otherwise they won't be linked

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<h3><?=$question?></h3>
<ol>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="question[<?=$id?>]" value="<?=$answer1?>" />
            <?=$answer1?>             
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="question[<?=$id?>]" value="<?=$answer2?>" />
            <?=$answer2?>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="question[<?=$id?>]" value="<?=$answer3?>" />
            <?=$answer3?>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="question[<?=$id?>]" value="<?=$answer4?>" />
            <?=$answer4?>
        </label>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Problems with your code:

- You can't repeat `id="php"`, because the `id`s must be unique!
- If you are only adding those `id`s because of `label`'s `for`, you can get rid of them and just place the `input` inside the `label`.
- Consider using `echo` shortcut syntax: `<?=$id?>` instead of `<?php echo $id ?>`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions..i want to apply order list at question level which is being rendered using line  <h3><?=$question?></h3> and not at at radio options.. radio options are just multi choice answer to question. Hope you understand my requirement.